# Terminal map operation not getting invoked in Mono

Tags: java, stream, reactor

Here's the relevant code:

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> res = remoteCall(HttpMethod.POST, issueTokenUrl, GsonConvertor.getInstance().serialize(request));

Mono<IssueToken> it = res.map(this::getIssueToken);
```

The remote call is successful (status code 200 with a nice response body), but the flow just won't go inside the `getIssueToken()` method. Here's the method:

```
private IssueToken getIssueToken(ResponseEntity<String> response) {
    System.out.println("Inside the method");    //this line won't print on the console
    HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();

    checkErrors(response);
    return GsonConvertor.getInstance().deserialize(response.getBody(), IssueToken.class);
  }
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`map(Function)` simply creates a new `Mono` but the trick is that the function is not evaluated directly. It is evaluated when you use it for example by calling `subscribe()`.